# Error with input shape in keras Sequential model

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

All welcome. Trying to deal with keras. I have several images saved in .npy format, as well as their labels.

When training a model, I get an error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (135, 240) but got array with shape (240, 3)

Which is very strange, because the shape of the submitted image is:

> (135, 240, 3)

My class NeuralNetwork:

```
class NeuralNetwork():
    def __init__(self):

    self.model = keras.models.Sequential()
    self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024, input_shape=(135, 240), activation="relu"))
    self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"))
    self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(9, activation="softmax"))

    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
    self.model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=["accuracy"])

    def FitModel(self, trainX, trainY):
        self.model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=30)


    def Predict(self, image):
        predictions = self.model.predict(image)

        choice = np.argmax(predictions[0])
        return choice
```

And main:

```
Data_Count = 7990

WIDTH = 240
HEIGHT = 135

nn = NeuralNetwork()

for i in range(1, DataCount+1):

    file_name = 'D:/TrainingData/training_data-{}.npy'.format(i)
    train_data = np.load(file_name)

    image = np.array([i[0] for i in train_data])[0]
    label = np.array([i[1] for i in train_data])[0]

    image = image / 255

    nn.FitModel(image, label)
```

Why she get only (240, 3), instead (135, 240)?

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: If I at all understand what's going on, you are loading single images of shape (135,240,3). Axis 0 of this is the 135, so you are passing 135 arrays of shape (240,3) to your input layer. I might be wrong, and you might even be passing a (1,240,3); can't check this. Anyway; the problems are with the for loop in `main`, the input dimensionality in the input layer and any other non-reproducible issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input_shape for dense-layer is not correct. Your images, have shape `(135, 240, 3)` but you feed `(135,240)` which means you miss the image channels. In addition, you forget to Flatten the images before feeding them into dense-layer. Here is the example with some dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import keras

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(135, 240, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(9, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])

# dummy data
images = np.zeros(shape=(7990, 135, 240, 3))
labels = np.zeros(shape=(7990, 9))

# train model
model.fit(x=images, y=labels, batch_size=128)
```